# How can select different drop down value everytime in for loop

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

My aim is to add the different drop down value  3 times in the script.

By using for I am able to select and add the same value 3 times but want to select and add the different drop down value every time.

Right now  i am able add the same skill three times but i want to add three.

Please suggest how can different value every time the loop executes
here is the code which i am using right now.

```
for(int i=0; i<=2; i++){
        Select skill = new Select(m1.findElement(By.xpath(".//select[@id='skill']")));
        skill.selectByValue(skills);
        Select proficiency = new Select(m1.findElement(By.xpath(".//select[@name='proficiency']")));
        proficiency.selectByValue("3");
        m1.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[@id='addskill']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Comment: How many options are there in skill dropdown ?

Comment: I would also suggest you to initialize 'skill' and 'proficiency' only once that too outside the for loop.

Comment: there are 14 value in skill drop down and i have to select at least three different skill value everytime the  for loops execute

Comment: <select name="skill" id="skill">
                                            <option value="">Select skill</option>
                                           \n<option value="6">AngularJS</option>\n<option value="12">Cake PHP framework</option>\n<option value="13">CI PHP framework</option>\n<option value="10">Dot Net</option>\n<option value="7">HTML5</option>\n<option value="2">Java</option>\n<option value="3">JavaScript</option>\n<option value="4">Jquery</option>\n<option value="5">JqueryAjax</option>\n<option value="9">MSSQL</option>\n<option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want add diffrent dropdown value 3 times use dropdown.selectByIndex(index).

```
Select skill = new Select(m1.findElement(By.xpath(".//select[@id='skill']")));
Select proficiency = new Select(m1.findElement(By.xpath(".//select[@name='proficiency']")));

for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){      
    skill.selectByIndex(i);
    proficiency.selectByIndex(i);
    m1.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[@id='addskill']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

OR

1. For random value selection in the drop down items.You need know how many items are their in the dropdown first.

```
    Select skill = new Select(m1.findElement(By.xpath(".//select[@id='skill']")));
    List<WebElement> listOptionDropdown = skill.getOptions();
    int dropdownCount = listOptionDropdown.size();


    Select proficiency = new Select(m1.findElement(By.xpath(".//select[@name='proficiency']")));
    List<WebElement> listOptionDropdown1 = skill.getOptions();
    int dropdownCount1 = listOptionDropdown1.size();


    for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){  

        int random = (int)(Math.random());
        random = random*dropdownCount +1;   
        skill.selectByIndex(random);
        int random1 = (int)(Math.random());
        random1 = random1*dropdownCount1 +1;  
        proficiency.selectByIndex(random1);
        m1.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[@id='addskill']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
```

Comment: This answer will hold true if you want to add only the first 3 values of the dropdown. If you want to add different values, then generate a random number each time inside the for loop and pass the value here - skill.selectByIndex(random);
proficiency.selectByIndex(random); Also make sure to generate the random values between 1 to the total options present inside the dropdown

Comment: @sers, Thanks a lot for editing.I appreciate your effort.

Comment: @AritroSen : That's true.However I have provided the solution how he can achieve to select 3 different value.

Comment: thanks a lot, this method is working fine for me. can u elaborate the random number generation method it will be useful for me in next task

Comment: sorry for disturbing u actually, I am new on StackOverflow  so can u please tell me how can I accept your  code

Comment: I have updated my code with random value as well.Please accept my code with click on accept button of code message once you receive.